# Swift NSEvent not working

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Below is my simple **AppDelegate.swift** class.

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyDownMask, handler: keyDown);
    }

    func keyDown(event:NSEvent!) {
        print("key down is \(event.keyCode)");
    }

}
```

How come key down events are not being printed? What am I missing?
I've tried searching around but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to `NSEvent.h` on `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`:

> Key-related events may only be monitored if accessibility is enabled
>   or if your application is trusted for accessibility access (see
>   AXIsProcessTrusted in AXUIElement.h). Note that your handler will not
>   be called for events that are sent to your own application.

Comment: this worked, went into Security & Privacy -> Accessibility -> Allowed my app

Comment: Which path should I specify to test the NSEvent feature while developing?

Comment: There are a lot of clipboard managers that don't require this and they still respond to key presses, how do they do it? I myself had to allow it, but later i removed it and is still working.

Comment: @CristiBăluță -  There is an old method of intercepting global shortcuts that comes from the Carbon Framework, that was basically created for NextOS, the predecessor of OSX. Apple is deprecating Carbon. Now everybody will be forced to use this draconian method.

Answer (score 9):

In order to use `NSEvent` globally as you currently have it you would have to allow your application to be trusted through accessibility settings. If you want to use `NSEvent` locally you could do:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyDownMask, handler: keyDown);
}

func keyDown(event: NSEvent!) -> NSEvent {
    NSLog("key down is \(event.keyCode)");
    return event
}
```

Comment: accepted the other guys answer cause he was first, but thanks for the help